# How do I fix this NullPointerException?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have a NullPointerException in my game and I am not sure what that is.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at www.Dragons.JFrames.Launcher.render(Launcher.java:47)
```

Line 47 reads:

```
launcher.add(content);
```

Please Help!

Comment: can't help with just 1 line of code. what is the contents in `content`?

Comment: Try posting maybe the entire method, or the method that sets content, or the method that initializes launcher?

Comment: share the code block which throws the exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like launcher hasn't been initialized (is null). What is launcher referencing? I would try checking where you begin using launcher and make sure that you are initializing it.

Comment: or maybe content is null and that add() method doesn't check the passed in value and perform some action on it?